# Navigation from structure with field Entries for URL

Tags: structure, navigation, entries-field, craft4

I am new to craftcms and searching did not get any answer. I have 2 fields setup navUrl (type entries) and customUrl (url) and I have a section called mainMenu with these fields. I have then added the entries for this section with each navUrl pointing to the structure entries (home, about etc).

For example my site has

Home
Blog
about
contact

In template I am can access the title, customUrl but unable to access navUrl which has the url for home page, about page etc.

How do I access the url which is selected in navUrl? doing a dump actually shows the field navUrl as null!

[Getting the URI of an Entries field in a Structure with no URLs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/getting-the-uri-of-an-entries-field-in-a-structure-with-no-urls) - solution mentioned doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The entries field will give you its value in the form of an [`EntryQuery`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#querying-entries), which you can execute to get the actual entry. I'm guessing your `navUrl` field allows only one entry? In this case, it's best to execute the query with `.one()`, which will return either the entry selected in the field or `null` if no entry is selected.

```twig
{% set navEntries = craft.entries().section('mainMenu').all() %}

{% for entry in navEntries %}
    {% set linkedEntry = entry.navUrl.one() %}
    {% set targetUrl = linkedEntry ? linkedEntry.getUrl() : entry.customUrl %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can reduce that to a handy one-liner with the null coalescing operator:

```twig
{% set navEntries = craft.entries().section('mainMenu').all() %}

{% for entry in navEntries %}
    {% set targetUrl = entry.navUrl.one().getUrl() ?? entry.customUrl %}
%}
{% endfor %}
```